# the namespace RoleExists does not exist in the namespace error

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

Based on [this link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs) I created a Role, but I got the following error:

> The namespace RoleExists does not exist in the namespace testproject.

Roles and my code is shown below:

```
namespace testproject.Roles
{
    public partial class ManageRoles : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void CreateRoleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string newRoleName = RoleName.Text.Trim();

            if (!Roles.RoleExists(newRoleName)) // Create the role 
                Roles.CreateRole(newRoleName); 

            RoleName.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an ambiguity in Roles: replace

```
if (!Roles.RoleExists(newRoleName)) // Create the role
```

with

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.RoleExists(newRoleName))
```